# Primitive roots of $2^{16} + 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I have a primitive root $ \alpha $ of a number $ p = 2^{16} + 1$.
How can I show if $ \alpha^{3} $ and $\alpha^{14}$ are primitive roots as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Use  the Gauss Theorem: If $a$ is a primitive root  then all primitive roots have  the form $a^s$, $(s,p-1)=1,$ $p$ -  prime number.